# Deploy Outlook add-in to Office Store

Tags: outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, office365

I made add-in for outlook and want to release it to store.office.com.

1. I have dev license for office 365.
2. I made add-in for Outlook using Visual Studio and everything works.
3. I found Microsoft Seller Dashboard, where I can add my application.
4. But on second step it asking me to provide app package xml file with all configurations, so it means, that I should care about add-in deployment myself(it is not like on chrome store for example where you provide package with all files and google deploy it)? 
   I should provide you only xml config? Where I can deploy it? MS Azure as C# app? I seen that this is what Visual Studio suggest me?
   Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manifest '.xml' file is the xml file that you need to upload (you are right, it isn't a package - that wording is for SharePoint apps and is confusing).

Make sure that you are using the manifest that has the full URL references and not the localhost references that VS creates while debugging.  You host all of the HTML+JS resources on your server so those don't need to be uploaded.

Comment: you also can use [Office App Compatibility Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46831) it  is a tool to check your app before submission to the Apps for Office Store.

Answer (score 1):

You are responsible for hosting all the HTML files referenced by the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that you have developed a COM Add-in using the Visual Studio Tools for Office project template (for desktop/client add-ins), and not a Mail App using the Apps for Office template (for web add-ins that work with OWA/Outlook.com).  The Office Store is meant to host Apps for Office/Office Web Add-ins (the new name), and Microsoft provides no central marketplace for selling desktop add-ins.

Comment: No, the question is about Office Apps.